# Android & indirectly referenced jars = BAD?

Tags: android, eclipse

I have an Android project (in Eclipse) that references another plain Java project. This other plain Java project references some jar libraries. My Problem:

At compile time everything seems fine. However, when I run the Android project I get a class not found error related to classes in the indirectly referenced jar libraries.

I have marked them as "exported" in the Java build settings. If I manually include the jar file in the Android project it works, however, sometimes (most times) I get a "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: ..." error because the dalvik compiler seems to find these jars twice (that happens even if I remove the jar from the "exported" list).

Any ideas how to solve this?

Thanks,
Daniel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the dependencies of your included project become the dependencies of your current project. I would:

1. JAR up your dependent project(s) and include it in your current project as a JAR.
2. Include the dependent JARs of your dependent project(s) in your current project.

This helps keep your work space tidier and insures your current project always has the appropriate resources locally. You can always create a script to build your dependent projects and deposit the JARs into your current project.

Comment: Thanks. This is basically the same thing I described below (which you voted down and believed to be worth only a comment). Either way, you forgot to mention the downsides (re-run the build scripts every time something changes, no hotcode replacement,...). It's a workaround, not a solution.

Comment: Sorry, I misinterpreted it as a comment, not a solution.

Answer (score 0):

well, I've now worked around it with a build script that jars all my dependent projects, so I can reference that jar only (and avoid the reference to the Java project).

Works, but now I need to rebuild every time I make a change (AND hit refresh in eclipse so it realizes that a referenced jar has changed). Still hoping there is a "real" solution to this..